# Does JMESPath have an identity function?

Tags: jmespath

In the jq filtering language the `.` filter expression simply returns the input JSON unaltered (except for pretty printing). E.g.

```
$ echo '{"foo": true, "bar": 42}' | jq '.'
{
  "foo": true,
  "bar": 42
}
```

Does JMESPath have a similar expression (aka [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [current-node](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#current-node) operator performs this function in JMESPath, e.g.

```
$ echo '{"foo": true, "bar": 42}' | ~/.local/go/bin/jp @
{
  "bar": 42,
  "foo": true
}
```

Thanks to jdevillard on https://gitter.im/jmespath/chat for the answer.